# Signup page error message in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on my making a sample app from Rails Tutorial by Micheal Hartl. 
I was working on the errors on my sign up page and I came across an issue im not able to solve.

[image: Screenshot of the error messages]

Here after the 5 listed error messages theres an unwanted array listing the same error messages.

Here's the HTML

```
<%= provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation"%>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

    <%= f.submit "Create My Account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

And here's the error message partial:

```
 <% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explaination">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error")%>

    </div>
    <ul>
      <%= @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And SCSS file:

```
/* FORMS */
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input{
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}

input{
  height: auto !important;
}

#error_explaination{
  color: red;
  ul{
    color: red;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  }
}

.field_with_errors{
  @extend .has-error;
  .form-control{
    color: $state-danger-text;
  }
}
```

**Help me out. Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `<%= @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>` line. When you use equal sign (i.e. `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`) ERB evaluates and prints an expression.

Change to `<% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>`.